# One response after few async functions

Tags: mysql, node.js, rest, architecture

I have a web page with a form where a user can edit personal info, education, work history and etc.
And the user can add more than one degree, for example: bs, ms, phd. And a few job positions as well.

When the user push 'save' button I send all this data to my server. I send it all in one request. In the server I have a point to handle the request.

```
app.post(config.version + '/profile', (req, res, next) => {});
```

And there I do a few MySQL queries to insert/update/delete a data. I use `mysql` package from npm to do that.

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const userQuery = `INSERT INTO user ...;`;
    const degreesQuery = 'INSERT INTO degree ...;';
    const positionsQuery = 'UPDATE position SET ...;';

    this.connection.query(userQuery, err => {});
    this.connection.query(degreesQuery, err => {});
    this.connection.query(positionsQuery, err => {});

    resolve({});
})
```

In the end I do `resolve({})` but I want to select updated profile and send it back (because in MySQL tables for degrees I add ids that helps me to not insert again duplicate data). So, my question is how to do `resolve({})` only when all my async `this.connection.query`s finished?

Comment: If you want specific code help, you will need to add to your question exactly which database module you are using because people need to know that interface and whether it supports the use of promises for tracking asynchronous results.

Comment: @jfriend00 I am sorry, you right. I updated the question

Comment: Related: [Node.js, MySQL and promises](https://codeburst.io/node-js-mysql-and-promises-4c3be599909b)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion is to run all the queries in a Promise.all().

Example:

```
const queries = [
    `INSERT INTO user ...;`;,
    'INSERT INTO degree ...;',
    'UPDATE position SET ...;'
];

Promise.all(queries.map((query) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
         this.connection.query(query, err => {
             return err ? reject(err) : resolve();
         });
    });
})
.then(() => {
    // continue
    // get your updated data here with and send it as response
})
```

If your db library has support for Promise write it this way

```
Promise.all(queries.map((query) => {
    return this.connection.query(query);
})
.then(() => {
    // continue
    // get your updated data here with and send it as response
})
```

Comment: Shouldn't you just be using the built-in promise support in the DB library?

Comment: Of course if there is, I don't know which library the poster is using. But if it has support for Promises just use the promises. I will update my answer with that in mind.

Comment: The specific db package has been added to the question by the OP.

Comment: It seems mysql package does not provide Promise style, it does provide streams but in that case it won't help as you would still have to count occurrences of 'end' event, so wrapping the callback is the best option IMO.